# Is the topology induced by a norm an initial topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(V,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological vector space where $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology induced by a norm

$$\Vert \cdot \Vert: V \to [0, \infty[$$

Is it true that $\mathcal{T}$ is the initial topology w.r.t. this norm?

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the initial topology generated by this norm. I can see that $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{T}$ must hold but does the other inclusion also hold?

EDIT: the other inclusion also seems to hold:

Consider the ball $B_{\Vert \cdot \Vert}(0,\epsilon)$. Since this is the inverse image of the open set $[0, \epsilon[$ under the norm map, we see that $B_{\Vert \cdot \Vert}(0, \epsilon) \in \mathcal{S}$. Since $(V, \mathcal{S})$ is also a topological vector space, all translates of this ball are also in $\mathcal{S}$. Thus $\mathcal{S}$ contains a basis of $\mathcal{T}$, and we must have $\mathcal{T}\subseteq \mathcal{S}$ as well.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the norm function $n(x)=\|x\|: V \to \Bbb R_0^+$, it's certainly true that $\mathcal{T}$, the induced topology by that norm on $V$, does make $n$ continuous, so for $\mathcal{T}_n$ (the initial topology induced by $n$ on $V$) we can surely say $$\mathcal{T}_n \subseteq \mathcal{T}$$ by minimality.

The reverse is certainly not true: Because we have an initial topology induced by a single function, $$\mathcal{T}_n = \{n^{-1}[O]: O \subseteq \Bbb R^+_0 \text{ open}\}$$ and this implies that if $n(x)=n(x')$ for $x,x' \in V$ and any open $O \in \mathcal{T}_n$: $x \in O \iff x' \in O$, so $V$ in $\mathcal{T}_n$ is not $T_0$ and so quite different from the metric topology $\mathcal{T}$.

However, if we use the notion of a weak **vector-space** topology, things change: the minimal vector space topology $\mathcal{T}_{n,v}$ (making the $+,-,\cdot$ operations continuous) that also makes $n$ continuous, has the property that all norm-open balls are open in $\mathcal{T}_{n,v}$ as you state and then the fact that all operations are continuous allows you to translate those to all other points as well. So trivially yes to your title question, if we work in the category of TVS's and trivially no if we work in the category Top.

Comment: Well, it was obviously (or perhaps not obviously? :-) not trivial for the OP (nor for me).

Comment: Hmm, now I wonder where my reasoning goes wrong?

Comment: It is known that if $\mathcal{T}$ is a collection of seminorms on $V$, then the initial topology, call it $\mathcal{S}$, gives a topological vector space $(V, \mathcal{S})$. Thus the vector space operations are continuous w.r.t. this topology, in particular translates.  My answer for the other inclusion must contain a flaw somewhere, but I can't locate where it is.

Comment: @user745578 that is *one* notion of initial topology, with seminorms. That always gives a vector space topology. The general topology notion is different.

Comment: I see what I forgot, I must also allow all translates of this norm to get a topological vector space. Thanks for your answer! It was very elegant

Comment: @user745578 a vector space topology is determined by the open neighbourhoods of $0$, general topologies aren't.

Comment: Yes, I know. For future readers, note that the statement becomes true when we consider the family $\{v \mapsto \Vert v-z \Vert: z \in V\}$ instead to get the initial topology. Then this determines a topological vector space and the argument goes through.

Comment: @user745578 I agree. Then you do use the normal initial topology notion, but on way more functions. You make it explicitly translation invariant that way.

Comment: Indeed, that was the source of my confusion. But your answer resolved it and gave a nice example why we need the translations (otherwise things can go wrong badly, the space is not even $T_0$ anymore)